# TornadoFX Fragment OpenWindow is always on top

Tags: kotlin, tornadofx

I'm working with TornadoFX's `fragment` class, and opening each new `fragment` within a new window using it's `openWindow()` method.

The window opens and everything works well. I've set the modality to `Modality.NONE` so the original screen can be accessed while the new fragment is active.

The problem that I'm having is that the new window is *always* on top, so I have to move it to access the original window underneath which isn't ideal.

Is this by design/is there anyway to change this behaviour?

I've been playing around with the `openWindow()`s `owner =` parameter, setting it to null and another `Stage` but nothing seems to work.

First, the code that opens the window, `view` is the fragment.

```
//h here is just the histogram, an int[] 
val hisScope = HistogramScope(h, pointerVM.APUFile.file.name)

//view declared using the find method.
val view = find<Histogram>(hisScope)

view.whenUndocked {
  closeChart(pointerVM)
}

//code checks to see if the requested histogram is already open
val matchingRnameHistograms = isMatchingRnameOpen(pointerVM)

if (map.size == 0 || matchingRnameHistograms.isEmpty()) {

view.openWindow(stageStyle = StageStyle.UTILITY, modality = Modality.NONE, resizable = false, owner = null, block = false)

map.put(pointerVM, view) //record which histograms are open

} else { //.. not too relevant }
```

Next, this is how i've declared the fragment with the scope:

```
class Histogram : Fragment() {

override val scope = super.scope as HistogramScope

override val root = hbox{

    hgrow = Priority.ALWAYS
    vgrow = Priority.ALWAYS

    style{
        minWidth = 1280.px
        minHeight = 250.px
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If the window is not modal it shouldn't be always on top. Please post a minimal code sample that exhibits the issue.

Comment: Hi @EdvinSyse, thanks for the reply. I've added some code above - I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you open a new window in context of another, the `owner` attribute is by default set to the originating UIComponent. You can pass `owner = null` to `openWindow` to prevent this, thus allowing the window to be placed below the originating one. Here is a complete app showing how this works:

```
class MyApp : App(MainView::class)

class MainView : View() {
    override val root = stackpane {
        setPrefSize(800.0, 600.0)
        button("Open new window").action {
            find<NewWindow>().openWindow(owner = null)
        }
    }
}

class NewWindow : Fragment() {
    override val root = label("I'm not modal!")
}
```

If you still can't get it to work, try to reduce the number of factors in your code :)

[image]

Comment: Thanks Edvin, that works well! It's weird how making `owner = null` the only parameter works. I'd set that parameter in the initial code, but alongside others like `modality` and `stageStyle`. Do certain parameters default the `owner` back to the originating UIComponent?

Comment: No, they shouldn't overwrite `owner`. Can you change my example code by adding parameters so it doesn't work? Remember that modality options would control, well.. modality :) hehe

Comment: Edvin, while this method does indeed work for stopping the fragment from staying on top, I end up losing the convenience of having an owner. For example, now when I close my main view, the fragment does not close automatically. Is the only work around to keep a list of all my child views/fragments and close them manually?

Comment: No, you could either fire an event when the parent closes, or you could pass the parent to the child and have it listen to when the parent closes for example.